# Combine and align every two lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How to use `sed`, `awk` or `bash` to most succinctly convert the file format A to B below ?

**A**

```
1
blabla
2
another blabla
... (more omitted)
10
yet another blabla
...
100
final blabla
```

**B**

```
1   blabla
2   another blabla
...
10  yet another blabla
...
100 final blabla
```

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. We (maybe) help with #3. The other two are entirely YOUR responsibility.

Comment: Actually, @MarcB, according to the help page here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, what you say only applies to questions asking for help with homework problems. I don't see anything there or in the 'what not to ask' page that would indicate that this question is off-topic or unsuitable.

Comment: @ccarton: I'd say it's a safe bet that when these sorts of things show up with absolutely NO hint of even having attempted anything themselves, it's pretty much "this is my homework, I'm too lazy to do it myself. you do it for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many different ways, here is one using `paste`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
1
blabla
2
another blabla
10
yet another blabla
100
final blabla

$ paste - - < ip.txt 
1   blabla
2   another blabla
10  yet another blabla
100 final blabla
```

See [How to process a multi column text file to get another multi column text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308631/how-to-process-a-multi-column-text-file-to-get-another-multi-column-text-file) for many more methods

Answer (score 0):

In one bash line:

```
while read line1; do if read line2; then echo "$line1" "$line2"; fi; done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pr` in `Bash`:

```
$ pr -2 -a -s\  -t foo2
1 blabla
2 another blabla
10 yet another blabla
100 final blabla
```